# get noderef from document guid using (bakend) java?

Tags: java, alfresco

Alfresco Javascript API has a search.findNode("workspace://SpacesStore/" + **documentguid**) method, that giving a guid of a document (node), one can get the noderef of the document.

How to get this "org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef" using java (backend java), having only the document/node guid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [NodeRef](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/repository/NodeRef.html) constructor :

> Construct a Node Reference from a string representation of a Node
>   Reference. NodeRef(String protocol, String identifier, String id)

Example :

```
NodeRef myNoderef = new NodeRef("workspace","SpacesStore",documentguid)
```

If you want to get more information of your document, or do some modification on it, you can use the [NodeService](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/repository/NodeService.html) of [FileFolderService](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/model/FileFolderService.html) (it depends of your needs) :

```
fileFolderService.getFileInfo(myNoderef)
```